Milvus Backup and Restore: Schema Compatibility Error with Different Vector Types
Does the Milvus backup and restore feature support transferring data between collections with different schemas? Specifically, I have two collections where most fields have the same name and type, except for the vector fields: collection v1 uses FloatVector(512) and collection v2 uses Float16Vector(512). Can I copy data from the v1 collection and import it into the v2 collection using Milvus version 2.4.4?
from pymilvus import Collection, connections, utility

connections.connect()

v1_collection = Collection("v1")
v2_collection = Collection("v2")

backup_files = utility.backup_collection("v1")

utility.restore_collection(backup_files, collection_name="v2")


No, it is not supported. You may need other tools to transform the data.
